# PowerShell hashtable question - office 365

Tags: powershell, office365

I need to set OOF message for around 80 users in O365.

I found a cmdlet Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration which I can use to automate the procedure,
and it's looks fine but I'am probably missing something.

Here is the code:

```
$usersfile = import-csv "C:\Users\Out Of office bulk\Users.csv"



$setmailbox = @{
'Identity' = $usersfile.UserPrincipalName
'AutoReplyState'  = 'Scheduled'
'externalaudience' = 'all'
'InternalMessage' = 'I am not here'
'ExternalMessage' = 'I am not here'
'StartTime' = '01/02/2020 01:00:00'
'EndTime' = '02/02/2020 23:00:00'
}

Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration @setmailbox
```

my issue is with the Identity parameter,

when I run the  `$setmailbox`

I can see that it showing the right UPN from the csv file:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
AutoReplyState                 Scheduled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
externalaudience               all                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Identity                       {blah@blah.com, blah2@blah.com}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
StartTime                      01/02/2020 01:00:00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
EndTime                        02/02/2020 23:00:00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
InternalMessage                I am not here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ExternalMessage                I am not here
```

But when I run the script, i'am getting this error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxLocationIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I've tried to change this:

```
'Identity' = $usersfile.UserPrincipalName
```

to almost any thing, and it didn't work.

Thanks a lot for your help.

PS:

I know that I can do something like that:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | ForEach-Object {
$user = $_."UserPrincipalName"
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration `
 -Identity $user -AutoReplyState Scheduled -StartTime "07/10/2018 01:00:00" ` 
 -EndTime "7/15/2018 23:00:00" -InternalMessage "I am not here" -ExternalMessage "I am not here."
}
```

but for practice purposes I prefer to do it with the hash table in order to understand it better.

Solution:
thanks to @Lee_Dailey, I didn't noticed that the `identity` parameter accepts only one user each time, so the solution for multi user is to use the `foreach-object`.

Comment: the MSDocs site says that parameter accepts ONE identity - and only one that maps to a `<MailboxIdParameter>`. your `$usersfile.UserPrincipalName` is a collection, not an individual item ... and you MUST give that cmdlet a single item.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thanks for your help,
i've looked at the MSDocs site, and it says :
```The Identity parameter specifies the mailbox that you want to modify. You can use any value that uniquely identifies the mailbox.``` how did you figure out that it's accepts only one Identity?

Comment: you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// those that accept more than one item show the `[]` in the parameter type. this >>> `[-Identity] <MailboxIdParameter>` <<< is for one item. a multi-item parameter is done thus >>> `[-EventsToDeleteIDs <String[]>]` <<<.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thank you very much, I forgot about that completely!! I've tried to figure this out for almost 2.5 hours  LOOL.
If so,I guess that my only way to achive this goal is by using the ```foreach-object``` cmdlet then .

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] the notation is fairly standard code syntax notation ... but it aint at all obvious unless you work at it. ///// yep, you will need to iterate thru the collection when dealing with one-at-a-time parameters.